# Using set theory to find the shape area in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, set-theory

So I'm given the following diagram:

[image]

And I'm being asked to find the area of each polygon given n.  The area is basically the sum of all blue squares since each square has an area of 1.  So when `n = 1`, the area is one.  When `n = 2`, the area is 5.  Because of the relationship between each polygon, I know that I could knock this down using set theory.

```
n  Area(n)

1  1
2  A(n-1) + (4 * (n-1)) = 5
3  A(n-1) + (4 * (n-1)) = 13
4  A(n-1) + (4 * (n-1)) = 25
5  A(n-1) + (4 * (n-1)) = 41
```

However, I didn't have as much luck trying to represent this in code:

```
def shapeArea(n):
    prev_output = 0
    output = 0

    if n == 1:
        output = 1
    elif n > 1:
        for i in range(n):
            prev_output = n-1 + (4 * (n-1))

    output = prev_output + (4 * (n-1))

    return output
```

For example:  For `n = 2`, I'm getting an output of 9 instead of 5.

Comment: Actually your code has few logical errors too that give 0 for n =1. I have edited it, you can see

Comment: 1. Its `output` not `ouput`, 2. the line `output = prev_output +...` should be inside `elif`, because when `n=1`, `n-1=0` and whole `output` is zero

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with set theory.  It could easily be solved with either iteration or recursion: your attempt failed because you're computing exactly the same `prev_output` value over and over, rather than building up from the n=1 case.  My approach would be to enter the known terms of the sequence into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (oeis.org), as they'll almost certainly have a formula for direct computation of the values: `2*n*(n+1)+1` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You were close :-)**

Here are the small fix-ups:

```
def shapeArea(n):
    output = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        output += 4 * i
    return output
```

Running this:

```
for n in range(1, 6):
    print(n, shapeArea(n))
```

Gives this output:

```
1 1
2 5
3 13
4 25
5 41
```

Comment: :) was about to suggest that. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

of course with Gauss's theorem the code would look like this:

```
def ShapeArea(n):
    return 2*(n**2) - (2*n)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

In a recursive solution, it is much simple from your logic.

```
def shape_area(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return shape_area(n-1) + 4*(n-1)
```

Comment: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: Wah... will go with iteration then

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gauss' trick to make a closed-form formula:

```
2*Area(n) = 

    1   +   4    +    8    +   12   + ... + 4(n-1)
+
    1   + 4(n-1) +  4(n-2) + 4(n-3) + ... +   4 
--------------------------------------------------
    2   +  4n    +   4n    +   4n   + ... +  4n

= (n-1)4n + 2
= 4n^2 - 4n + 2
```

So Area(n) = 2n<sup>2</sup> - 2n + 1

Answer (score 0):

```
def shape_area(n):
    return sum([1] + [4*i for i in range(1, n)])
```